# Can't account for full time in MariaDB ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON output

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to optimize some queries in MariaDB, and I've found the ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON functionality to be extremely useful. However, in the case of some complex joins, I'm running into some examples where the time doesn't add up, or come close to it.

A when-it-works example, in the case of one query, the query_block r_total_time_ms was about 239ms; the query itself involved 11 tables, and one of those 11 was taking up nearly 227ms, accounting for the large majority of the time spent in the query. There was an obvious index change to make, and making it took that element down to less than 1 ms, and total query time to just over 1 ms.

But in another case, the query_block r_total_time_ms is a little over 163ms; the query involves 9 tables and/or subqueries, and the *highest* r_total_time_ms for any of the components is just over 15 ms. The *total* of all those components adds up to about 25 ms. So where is the rest of the time being spent? What's it doing for the other 140-ish ms? If there's a way to tell, I don't know what it is.

Here's the ANALYZE output that I'm struggling with:

```
ANALYZE
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "r_loops": 1,
    "r_total_time_ms": 163.18,
    "filesort": {
      "sort_key": "tcontent.lastUpdate",
      "r_loops": 1,
      "r_total_time_ms": 0.0147,
      "r_limit": 20,
      "r_used_priority_queue": false,
      "r_output_rows": 2,
      "r_buffer_size": "252",
      "temporary_table": {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "tcontent",
          "access_type": "index_merge",
          "possible_keys": [
            "IX_TContent",
            "IX_TContent_1",
            "IX_TContent_2",
            "IX_TContent_5",
            "IX_tcontent_mobileExclude",
            "IX_tcontent_displaystart",
            "IX_tcontent_displaystop",
            "IX_tcontent_approved",
            "IX_tcontent_active",
            "IX_tcontent_display",
            "IX_tcontent_type",
            "ntID_Type_subType_Display_DisplayStart_DisplayStop_mobileExclude",
            "ix_tcontent_SiteID_Active_Filename_Type"
          ],
          "key_length": "2,2,2,2,2,78,106",
          "index_merge": {
            "union": {
              "range": {
                "key": "IX_tcontent_display",
                "used_key_parts": ["Display"]
              },
              "range": {
                "key": "IX_tcontent_display",
                "used_key_parts": ["Display"]
              },
              "intersect": {
                "range": {
                  "key": "IX_tcontent_approved",
                  "used_key_parts": ["Approved"]
                },
                "range": {
                  "key": "IX_tcontent_active",
                  "used_key_parts": ["Active"]
                },
                "range": {
                  "key": "IX_tcontent_display",
                  "used_key_parts": ["Display"]
                },
                "range": {
                  "key": "IX_TContent_2",
                  "used_key_parts": ["SiteID"]
                },
                "range": {
                  "key": "IX_TContent_5",
                  "used_key_parts": ["ModuleID"]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "r_loops": 1,
          "rows": 2583,
          "r_rows": 3966,
          "r_total_time_ms": 15.183,
          "filtered": 96.129,
          "r_filtered": 98.664,
          "attached_condition": "tcontent.Active = 1 and tcontent.Approved = 1 and tcontent.searchExclude = 0 and tcontent.SiteID = 'CAE' and tcontent.ModuleID = '00000000000000000000000000000000000' and tcontent.ContentID <> '00000000000000000000000000000000001' and tcontent.`Type` <> 'Module' and (tcontent.Display = 1 or tcontent.Display = 2 and (tcontent.DisplayStart <= '2018-01-09 15:17:00' and (tcontent.DisplayStop >= '2018-01-09 15:17:00' or tcontent.DisplayStop is null) or tcontent.DisplayStart <= '2019-01-09 15:17:00' and (tcontent.DisplayStop >= '2018-01-09 15:17:00' or tcontent.DisplayStop is null))) and (tcontent.mobileExclude is null or tcontent.mobileExclude in (0,1))"
        },
        "table": {
          "table_name": "<subquery2>",
          "access_type": "eq_ref",
          "possible_keys": ["distinct_key"],
          "key": "distinct_key",
          "key_length": "105",
          "used_key_parts": ["contentHistID"],
          "ref": ["func"],
          "r_loops": 3913,
          "rows": 1,
          "r_rows": 5.1e-4,
          "r_total_time_ms": 6.2577,
          "filtered": 100,
          "r_filtered": 100,
          "attached_condition": "tcontent.Display = 1 or tcontent.Display = 2 and (tcontent.DisplayStart <= '2018-01-09 15:17:00' and (tcontent.DisplayStop >= '2018-01-09 15:17:00' or tcontent.DisplayStop is null) or tcontent.DisplayStart <= '2019-01-09 15:17:00' and (tcontent.DisplayStop >= '2018-01-09 15:17:00' or tcontent.DisplayStop is null))",
          "materialized": {
            "unique": 1,
            "query_block": {
              "select_id": 2,
              "table": {
                "table_name": "tcontentcategories",
                "access_type": "ALL",
                "possible_keys": ["PRIMARY"],
                "r_loops": 1,
                "rows": 166,
                "r_rows": 166,
                "r_total_time_ms": 0.2246,
                "filtered": 100,
                "r_filtered": 0.6024,
                "attached_condition": "tcontentcategories.path like '%D3386B7B-5056-8740-7CA949A8C39FACF3%'"
              },
              "table": {
                "table_name": "tcontentcategoryassign",
                "access_type": "ref",
                "possible_keys": [
                  "PRIMARY",
                  "IX_tcontentcategoryassign_categoryID"
                ],
                "key": "IX_tcontentcategoryassign_categoryID",
                "key_length": "105",
                "used_key_parts": ["categoryID"],
                "ref": ["dbMuraCMS.tcontentcategories.categoryID"],
                "r_loops": 1,
                "rows": 53,
                "r_rows": 33,
                "r_total_time_ms": 0.0413,
                "filtered": 100,
                "r_filtered": 100,
                "using_index": true
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "table": {
          "table_name": "tfiles",
          "access_type": "eq_ref",
          "possible_keys": ["PRIMARY"],
          "key": "PRIMARY",
          "key_length": "105",
          "used_key_parts": ["fileID"],
          "ref": ["dbMuraCMS.tcontent.FileID"],
          "r_loops": 2,
          "rows": 1,
          "r_rows": 1,
          "r_total_time_ms": 0.0109,
          "filtered": 100,
          "r_filtered": 100,
          "attached_condition": "trigcond(trigcond(tcontent.FileID is not null))"
        },
        "table": {
          "table_name": "tcontentstats",
          "access_type": "eq_ref",
          "possible_keys": ["PRIMARY"],
          "key": "PRIMARY",
          "key_length": "182",
          "used_key_parts": ["contentID", "siteID"],
          "ref": ["dbMuraCMS.tcontent.ContentID", "dbMuraCMS.tcontent.SiteID"],
          "r_loops": 2,
          "rows": 1,
          "r_rows": 0,
          "r_total_time_ms": 0.0127,
          "filtered": 100,
          "r_filtered": 100,
          "attached_condition": "trigcond(trigcond(tcontent.ContentID is not null and tcontent.SiteID is not null))"
        },
        "table": {
          "table_name": "tparent",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "IX_TContent",
            "IX_TContent_2",
            "IX_tcontent_active",
            "ntID_Type_subType_Display_DisplayStart_DisplayStop_mobileExclude",
            "ix_tcontent_SiteID_Active_Filename_Type"
          ],
          "key": "IX_TContent",
          "key_length": "106",
          "used_key_parts": ["ContentID"],
          "ref": ["dbMuraCMS.tcontent.ParentID"],
          "r_loops": 2,
          "rows": 1,
          "r_rows": 238,
          "r_total_time_ms": 1.5375,
          "filtered": 100,
          "r_filtered": 0.4202,
          "attached_condition": "trigcond(tcontent.Display = 1 or tcontent.Display = 2 and (tparent.`Type` <> 'Calendar' and tcontent.DisplayStart <= '2018-01-09 15:17:00' and (tcontent.DisplayStop >= '2018-01-09 15:17:00' or tcontent.DisplayStop is null) or tparent.`Type` = 'Calendar' and tcontent.DisplayStart <= '2019-01-09 15:17:00' and (tcontent.DisplayStop >= '2018-01-09 15:17:00' or tcontent.DisplayStop is null))) and trigcond(tparent.SiteID = tcontent.SiteID and tparent.Active = 1 and trigcond(tcontent.ParentID is not null))"
        },
        "table": {
          "table_name": "tcontentfilemetadata",
          "access_type": "ALL",
          "possible_keys": [
            "IX_tcontentfilemetadata_contenthistid",
            "IX_tcontentfilemetadata_fileid"
          ],
          "r_loops": 2,
          "rows": 1,
          "r_rows": 0,
          "r_total_time_ms": 0.0045,
          "filtered": 100,
          "r_filtered": 100,
          "attached_condition": "trigcond(tcontentfilemetadata.fileid = tcontent.FileID and tcontentfilemetadata.contenthistid = tcontent.ContentHistID)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see "intersect".  That usually means that you don't have a 'composite' index would work significantly better.  Please provide the `SELECT` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: In this case, it was really bad table design on the part of a third-party software developer. There were, in fact, good (almost perfect) composite indices on the table, but they also had a singleton index on virtually every column in the table. Including several columns whose only values table-wide were 0 or 1. I'm not sure why it was preferring the bad singleton indexes (plus an intersect) over the composite index, but once I dropped the bad singleton indices, it started using the good composite index and the execution time dropped by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Thanks for that anecdote.

Comment: I'm still relatively new to MariaDB. Hopefully I'll figure out how to better capture specifics in the future. With any luck, I may still have the specifics here.